# HTML Javascript calculator calculation bug

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't get the result when I press calculate when I added the `<select>` can you please identify the problem here?

I also want some text to be shown along with the result I want to show 2 results in the result box with text like

```
Width: result
```

and

```
Length: result
```

```js
// searching <form id="calculateForm"> and waiting for submitting
document.querySelector('#calculateForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent submitting form (reload page for example)
  result(); // your calculating
})

function result() {
  const x = document.querySelector("#constant").value;
  var unit1 = document.getElementById("unit1").value;
  if (unit1 == "in") {
    x = Number(x) * 0.0254
  }
  if (unit1 == "mm") {
    x = Number(x) * 0.001
  }
  if (unit1 == "cm") {
    x = Number(x) * 0.01
  }
  const y = document.querySelector("#height").value;
  var unit2 = document.getElementById("unit2").value;
  if (unit2 == "in") {
    y = Number(y) * 0.0254
  }
  if (unit2 == "mm") {
    y = Number(y) * 0.001
  }
  if (unit2 == "cm") {
    y = Number(y) * 0.01
  }
  const z = document.querySelector("#freq").value;
  var unit3 = document.getElementById("unit3").value;
  if (unit3 == "mhz") {
    z = Number(z) * 10 ** 6
  }
  if (unit3 == "ghz") {
    z = Number(z) * 10 ** 9
  }
  const result = document.querySelector("#Calculate");
  if (unit4 == "in") {
    result = Number(result) * 0.0254
  }
  if (unit4 == "mm") {
    result = Number(result) * 0.001
  }
  if (unit4 == "result") {
    result = Number(result) * 0.01
  }

  let c = 3 * 10 ** 8;
  let k = Number(x) + 1;
  let k2 = k / 2;
  let k3 = Math.sqrt(k2);
  let y1 = Number(z) * 2;
  let w = c / (y1 * k3);

  result.textContent = w;
  result.style.display = "block"; // show it, because [display: none] by default

}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}

#calculateForm {
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* center form vertically */
}

.input-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* 10px bottom indent */
}

.input-wrapper label {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.43;
  color: #494949;
  display: block;
}

.input-wrapper input[type="text"] {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #878787;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0.8125rem 0.875rem;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  transition: border-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.input-wrapper input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0070be;
}

button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(108deg, #1999fb, #0039ac);
  background-color: #0070b8;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 11px 15px;
  min-width: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(110deg, #54baff, #0039ac 144%);
}

#Calculate {
  display: none;
  /* hide until getting results */
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #8cc1ec;
  background-color: #e0f1ff;
  padding: 1.4375rem 1.5625rem;
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<form id="calculateForm">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label for="constant">Di-Electric Constant:</label>
    <input type="text" id="constant" placeholder="Enter Value">
  </div>
  <div class="input_wrapper">
    <select id="unit1" class="input">
      <option value="in">Inches</option>
      <option value="cm">Centimeters</option>
      <option value="mm">Millimeters</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label for="height">Di-Electric Height:</label>
    <input type="text" id="height" placeholder="Enter Value">
    <select id="unit2" class="input">
      <option value="in">Inches</option>
      <option value="cm">Centimeters</option>
      <option value="mm">Millimeters</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label for="freq">Operational Frequency:</label>
    <input type="text" id="freq" placeholder="Enter Value">
    <select id="unit3" class="input">
      <option value="mhz">MHz</option>
      <option value="ghz">GHz</option>

    </select>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
  <select id="unit4" class="input">
    <option value="in">Inches</option>
    <option value="cm">Centimeters</option>
    <option value="mm">Millimeters</option>
  </select>
</form>

<div id="Calculate" style="display: block;"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix the errors you see in the console

Comment: Change all const to let and several vars to const: `let x = document.querySelector("#constant").value;
const unit1 = document.getElementById("unit1").value;`

Comment: Voting to close as a typo-type problem

Comment: You can use template literals to show more than one value: `result.textContent = \`Width: ${w}<br/>Length: ${len}\``

Comment: seems that you overwrite the `result` variable - initially declared `const result = document.querySelector("#Calculate");`  but then modified, like `result = Number(result) * 0.0254` and then treated once again as a DOM element when you do `result.textContent`?? confusing

Comment: That last piece of code using `result` variable makes no sense and does nothing to affect the final result as far as I can tell. For instance: `result = Number(result) * 0.0254` - what value do you expect `result` to have - it has been declared as a DOM element reference rather than a value

Comment: How do you hope to calculate `width` and `height`  type results? Are they different results or the same result but prefixed with either `width` or `height`?

Comment: I cant add the new line is textcontent

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the `Assignment to constant variable.` errors due to the misuse of `const` within the function there are other incomprehensible parts to this function.  Admittedly once the `const` declarations are replaced the function will return a value but the one of the last pieces of code does nothing because of the reference to a DOM element and not a value ( as per comment above ) so I took a leap of faith that this last portion of code was intended to alter the calculated result depending upon the unit selected. Much of the above is greatly simplified by using a lookup matrix to obtain the multiplier for the variables x,y,z and the result - w.

```js
const q=(e,n=document)=>n.querySelector(e);

q('#calculateForm').addEventListener('submit',result);



function result(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let matrix={
    mm:0.001,
    cm:0.01,
    in:0.0254,
    mhz:Math.pow(10,6),
    ghz:Math.pow(10,9),
    result:0.01,
    neo:011011100110010101101111 //  ;-)
  };
  let x=matrix[ q('#unit1').value ] * Number( q('#constant').value );
  let y=matrix[ q('#unit2').value ] * Number( q('#height').value );
  let z=matrix[ q('#unit3').value ] * Number( q('#freq').value );
  
  let c = 3 * Math.pow(10,8);
  let k = Number(x) + 1;
  let k2 = k / 2;
  let k3 = Math.sqrt(k2);
  let y1 = Number(z) * 2;
  let w = c / (y1 * k3);

  let result=matrix[ q('#unit4').value ] * w;

  q('#Calculate').textContent = result;
  q('#Calculate').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}

#calculateForm {
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* center form vertically */
}

.input-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* 10px bottom indent */
}

.input-wrapper label {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.43;
  color: #494949;
  display: block;
}

.input-wrapper input[type="text"] {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #878787;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0.8125rem 0.875rem;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  transition: border-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.input-wrapper input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0070be;
}

button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(108deg, #1999fb, #0039ac);
  background-color: #0070b8;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 11px 15px;
  min-width: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(110deg, #54baff, #0039ac 144%);
}

#Calculate {
  display: none;
  /* hide until getting results */
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #8cc1ec;
  background-color: #e0f1ff;
  padding: 1.4375rem 1.5625rem;
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<form id="calculateForm">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label for="constant">Di-Electric Constant:</label>
    <input type="text" id="constant" placeholder="Enter Value">
  </div>
  <div class="input_wrapper">
    <select id="unit1" class="input">
      <option value="in">Inches</option>
      <option value="cm">Centimeters</option>
      <option value="mm">Millimeters</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label for="height">Di-Electric Height:</label>
    <input type="text" id="height" placeholder="Enter Value">
    <select id="unit2" class="input">
      <option value="in">Inches</option>
      <option value="cm">Centimeters</option>
      <option value="mm">Millimeters</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <label for="freq">Operational Frequency:</label>
    <input type="text" id="freq" placeholder="Enter Value">
    <select id="unit3" class="input">
      <option value="mhz">MHz</option>
      <option value="ghz">GHz</option>

    </select>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
  
  <select id="unit4" class="input">
    <option value="in">Inches</option>
    <option value="cm">Centimeters</option>
    <option value="mm">Millimeters</option>
  </select>
</form>

<div id="Calculate" style="display: block;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've created the variable x as a constant.

```
  function result() {
          const x = document.querySelector("#constant").value;
```

But then again in a later section, you are trying to assign a value to x

```
if(unit1=="in")
{
x = Number(x) * 0.0254
}
```

Use

```
var x = document.querySelector("#constant").value;
```

Comment: Please do not answer so simple questions. Instead comment and when you have enough rep, vote to close

Comment: "simple"  as in he used the wrong command -> typo caused issue

Comment: just a last question how do I have text in the box of result it just shows the result but not text I want it like Width: (result)

Comment: When assigning the textContent, concatenate the other text you want. 

result.textContent = "Width :"+ w;